# Proof the identify $[h,x^n]=2n . x^{n}$ on a ring where $[x,y]=h$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let's $K$ be a ring, and for two elements of the ring we say $$[a,b]=ab-ba.$$

$x,y,h$ are elements of $K$ satisfying:
    $$[h,x]=2x ,\quad [x,y]=h.$$

Is it possible to prove the following identity: $[h,x^n]=2n.x^n$?

Comment: Why do you expect this equality to hold?  Have you seen it as an exercise? Have you realized it should be true by testing many examples? Or another reason?

Comment: It's just an exercice, and after basic expansion and recursion try out, I'm not sure how to go further to get the proof.

Comment: Can you prove it for $n=2$?

Comment: I try without success. Not sure how to expand further $[h,x^2]=hx^2-x^2h$ and   i also try to expand $ [h,x][h,x] =hxhx-hx^2h-xh^2+xhxh$, but i'm still block.

Comment: Let's write $[h,x^2] = hx^2 - x^2h = (hx^2 - xhx) + (xhx - x^2h)$.  Can you continue from there?

Comment: I got: $[h,x^2]= [h,x]x+x[h,x]=2x^2+x2x$. But is there a reason to commute $x2x$ into $2x^2$, in which case we get the proof for n=2?

Comment: Yes, if we use the distributivity, $2x= (1+1)x=x+x$ then we ended with $x2x=x(x+x)=x^2+x^2=2x^2$. Thank you for your hints. I will try to get the proof for n.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53800/discussion-between-xaving-and-pierre-guy-plamondon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the rule
$$
\mathbf{\color{red}{[a, b c]
=}}\
a b c - b c a
=
a b c - b a c + b a c - b c a\
\mathbf{\color{red}{=
[a, b] c + b [a, c]}},
$$
and then induction
$$
[h, x^{n}]
=
[h, x^{n-1} x]
=
[h, x^{n-1}] x + x^{n-1} [h, x]
=
2 (n-1) x^{n-1} x + x^{n-1} \cdot 2 x
=
2 n  x^{n}.
$$